# DialogFlow ES agent with API Webhook not giving the expected output

Tags: api, express, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Below is my API code

// Import required dependencies
`const express = require('express'); const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); const axios = require('axios');`

Create Express app

```
// Import required dependencies
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Configure app to use JSON body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Define endpoint to handle webhook requests from DialogFlow
app.post('/webhook', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Extract order ID from webhook request
    const orderId = req.body.orderId;

    // Make POST request to order status API with order ID
    const response = await axios.post('https://orderstatusapi-dot-organization-project-311520.uc.r.appspot.com/api/getOrderStatus', {
      orderId: orderId
    });

    // Extract shipment date from API response
    const shipmentDate = response.data.shipmentDate;

    // Convert shipment date to human-readable format (optional)
    const formattedShipmentDate = new Date(shipmentDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
      weekday: 'long',
      day: 'numeric',
      month: 'short',
      year: 'numeric'
    });

    // Construct webhook response
    const fulfillmentMessages = `The shipment date for order ID ${orderId} is ${formattedShipmentDate}.`;
    const responseJson = {
      fulfillmentMessages: fulfillmentMessages
    };

    // Send webhook response
    res.json(responseJson);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling webhook request:', error);
    // Send error response
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Start Express app on port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```

Now when I'm testing my ngrok API in postman with inputs

`{  "orderId":"31313" }`

It is giving me the output I'm expecting to give me which is below

`{ "fulfillmentMessages": "The shipment date for order ID 31313 is Thursday, Apr 20, 2023." }`

But when I'm using this https://074a-111-92-140-57.ap.ngrok.io/webhook API in my DialogFlow ES agent it is not giving me the above expected output

My User Inputs in DialogFlow ES Chatbot Agent are as follows:

> User: Hi

> Chatbot: Hi, How can I help you?

> User: Can I check my order status?

> Chatbot: What is your Order ID?

> User: My Order ID is "31313"

> Chatbot: No Response or Not available

> Expected Response: The shipment date for order ID 31313 is Thursday, Apr 20, 2023

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong???

[image]

[image]

[image]

Above is my DialogFlow ES settings.

Thank you all

Comment: Is it possible to share the documentation you are following to reproduce the issue?